# Can't open web applications when I double-click the project file

Tags: web-applications, visual-studio-2013

I'm not able to open my web applications for some reason. When I try to open it I get this:

[image]

I AM able to open **Windows Form Applications** without any problem, but somehow I can't open web applications. I'm using Visual Studio 2013

**UPDATE:**

So apparently I'm able to open it if I first open Visual Studio and then select "recent files" and open the project from there. But why can't I open file directly by clicking on the project file?

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you running? Are you maybe running "Express for Desktop Applications"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Comment: Are you opening the project or the solution? And did you look at the migration report?

Comment: I think I fount the problem. I have  Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate AND Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop Applications on my computer, but everytime I tried to open the project by opening the solution, it opened using Express for Desktop Applications. The problem is now fixed. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please add your success as an answer to the question. Please show the steps you took to figure it out, how someone else with the same problem could solve it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
I noticed that I had two Visual Studios on my computer: **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate** and  **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop Applications**.
Every time I opened a solution, the computer automatically tried opening it using **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop Applications**. This is the reason I was able to open Windows Form Applications but not Web forms.

So I just uninstalled the **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop Applications** so now the computer automatically opens solutions using **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate**